# ROS with standalone OpenCV library

Tags: opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
how could i use standalone OpenCV library with ROS?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11652/ros-with-standalone-opencv-library/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Use the [ROS Electric version](http://www.ros.org/wiki/opencv2#OpenCV_in_Electric). It uses the system `opencv` library. Diamondback and earlier releases distributed `opencv` as a ROS package.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-24**:
Thanks! Great! Could Electric use 2.1 version? And how could i convert OpenCV image to ROS format? and use it in ROS messages?